# Syntax error on an SQL select query linked to a combo box value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In the below query I am trying to retrieve a set of records based on the value in the combo box control 'cboDepartments'. I am getting a syntax error message on the join function for the routine below but don't understand why.

```
sql_get = "SELECT * FROM ([tblValueChain01] INNER JOIN [tblTeams] ON [tblValueChain01].[Team] = [tblTeams].[ID]) INNER JOIN ([tblContacts] ON [tblValueChain01].[TeamLead] = [tblContacts].[ID]) WHERE ((([tblTeams].[Team])= '" & cboDepartments.Value & "'))"
```

Me.frmstaticdatadepartments07.Form.RecordSource = sql_get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access you have to use the parentheses when you have more than one join. Try this:

```
sql_get = "SELECT * FROM ([tblValueChain01] 
      INNER JOIN [tblTeams] ON [tblValueChain01].[Team] = [tblTeams].[ID]) 
      INNER JOIN [tblContacts] ON [tblValueChain01].[TeamLead] = [tblContacts].[ID] 
      WHERE [tblTeams].[Team]= '" & cboDepartments.Value & "'"
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error message: missing operator

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua:- Updated the code. Please check now!

Comment: As the Americans say..  You are Awesome!!  thank you very much.

Comment: I still don't understand your logic however on the way you opened and closed the parenthesis ?

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua:- Sorry for a late response. But the reason why you require paranthese is because Access's join syntax supports joining only two tables at a time, so if you need to join more than two you need to enclose the extra ones in parentheses.

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua:- So you can understand it like this that you need to have n - 2 left parentheses after the from clause and one right parenthesis before the start of each new join clause except for the first, where n is the number of tables being joined together.